# Puma.NET DLL Recognition of car numbers

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, image-recognition

I want to make an application - license plate recognition from image. I use OpenCvSharp and Puma.NET.

But when I start my application,writes that the number is not found.

When I use breakpoints - Exception - "Recognition engine halted with code:0"

I loaded three dll - dibapi.dll, puma.net.dll, puma.interop.dll.

Why numbers are not recognized?

```
 public void RecognizePlate() // 
    {
        plateList.Clear();
        int i = 1;
        foreach(var plateImage in plate)
        {
            plateList.Add(i.ToString()+ " ) " + RunPuma(plateImage));
            i++;
        }
    }

    string RunPuma(IplImage img) // 
    {
        PumaPage Image = new PumaPage(img.ToBitmap());
        using (Image)
        {
            Image.FileFormat = PumaFileFormat.RtfAnsi; 
            Image.AutoRotateImage = true; 
            Image.FontSettings.DetectBold = true; 
            Image.FontSettings.DetectItalic = true;
            Image.EnableSpeller = false;
            Image.Language = PumaLanguage.English; 

            try
            {
                string s = Image.RecognizeToString();
                return s;
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return "This is NOT NUMBER";
            }
        }

        return "Error";
    }`
```

Comment: You may want to add more details to your question, like where the exception is happening. Is it crashing at Pumapage Image = new PumaPage() ?, step through your code and find out the exact location of exception. This will help to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Problem was fixed. I register APuma.dll in my system32.

Comment: Hi, My solution is working in Visual studio but exe gives error can you help?

Comment: How you register APuma.dll ?

Comment: anyone has these libraries please email me sjnilanr@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restart Visual Studio as Administrator and you should be able to work then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is an unsuccessful registration.

According the documentation, `apuma.dll` component should be registered during the installation. But `*.bat` file seems to be wrong, at least for my computer.

I solved problem with:

1. moving all files from `Puma.NET\COM Server\Register` to `Puma.NET\COM Server`
2. open console in `Puma.NET\COM Server` directory.
3. Typing this command: `regsvr32 APuma.dll`

If you get a successful registration message, George is your uncle!!

Comment: anyone has these libraries please email me sjnilanr@gmail.com